# Magento Events 'catalog_product_get_final_price' not working?

Tags: event-observer

below is my config.xml file code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Eventprice_Meta>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Eventprice_Meta>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <eventprice_meta>
                <class>Eventprice_Meta_Model_Observer</class>
            </eventprice_meta>
        </models>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_get_final_price><!-- observe the event -->
                <observers>
                    <eventprice_meta>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Eventprice_Meta_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>changeprice</method>
                    </eventprice_meta>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_get_final_price>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

below is my Observer.php files code.

```
<?php 
class Eventprice_Meta_Model_Observer {

    public function changeprice(Varien_Event_Observer $event) {
        return 5;
        if($_GET['id']){
            $pricetoadd=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->load($_GET['id'])->getPrice();

            $product = $event->getEvent()->getProduct();
            $originalprice = $product->getPrice();
            $customprice = $originalprice+$pricetoadd;
            $product->setPrice($customprice);
        }
        echo 'call';
        exit;
   }
}
```

i want to set the Product price $5 on product view page. i write a function 'changeprice' for changing the product price. but this function is not call please checked where i create a mistake in code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You declared your observer in the `<adminhtml>` area.  So it does not get triggered on frontend.
You need to replace

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
    ....
```

with

```
<frontend>
    <events>
    ....
```

Next problem.  `return 5;` will not make the price of the product `5`.  It will do nothing.
You need to make it `$observer->getProduct()->setFinalPrice(...your price here...)`

Next one.  Don't use `$_GET['id']`. Use `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id')`

And the last one for now. calling `return 5` at the top of the method will not execute the rest of the method. So you never reach `echo 'call'; exit;`

Comment: Perfect solution.+1 for me.

Comment: right Thanks awesome thanks this is working.

Answer (score 1):

### Observer parameters issue:

There are issue with parameters on observer.
For getting the `product id` try with `$observer->getProduct()->Id();`
As system when `catalog_product_get_final_price` event fire then the two parameter has been sended.

- Current product Object: `$event->getEvent()->getProduct()`;
- Other Qty: `$event->getEvent()->getQty()`.

**No need load product object again.**

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_get_final_price', array('product' => $product, 'qty' => $qty));
```

As @Marius told for set the final price,you need to use `$event->getEvent()->getProduct()->setFinalPrice()` for set final price and set  event area are from `adminhtml to frontend` for properly works.