# how to work on getFinalPrice() in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to change the product price to custom price through `getFinalPrice()` in product.php is there any way i am not getting how to do it ?

Comment: can you explain some more  specific?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add your own price calculation, use the `catalog_product_get_final_price` and `catalog_product_prepare_index_select` events. Using observer events is always better than rewriting models or codepool overrides.

The price index gets used for product listings. The final price event gets used for all other situations (product page, cart/quote, order placement).

Comment: actually i have made an attribute custom_price so i want to use its value instead of the original price of products so how could I do it , i am trying it through getFinalPrice() method but nothing happened

Comment: Well, then you're doing it wrong. Check out these answers: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69095/magento-events-catalog-product-get-final-price-not-working

Comment: But Erfan i applied according to the  link but it get applied only when I add product to cart i want to have the price on view and list page also and those pricing rules and product rules get apllied to it

Comment: So then the get_final_price observer works :) On the list page you need to use `catalog_product_prepare_index_select` to modify the price index, because that's where the price comes from in that scenario. The product view page should work for you as well, as that uses the get final price routine - not sure why that's not working for you

Comment: <events>
      
       <catalog_product_get_final_price>
        <observers>
          <ybizz_pricechange_observer>
            <class>ybizz_pricechange/observer</class>
            <method>getFinalPrice</method>
          </ybizz_pricechange_observer>
        </observers>
      </catalog_product_get_final_price>
</event>

Checkout i have used catalog_product_get_final_price event

Answer (score 0):

My observer

```
<?php
    class YBizz_PriceChange_Model_Observer  {

        public function getFinalPrice($observer) {
            $product = $observer->getProduct();
            $productIds = array($product->getId());
            $prices = $this->ProductPrice($productIds);
            $product->setPrice($new_price);
        }

        public function ProductPrice(array $productIds) {
            $item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productIds);

            if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                $item = $item->getParentItem();
            }

            if($item->getSuggested_price()){
                $new_price = $item->getSuggested_price();
            } else {
                $new_price = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
            }

            return $new_price; 
        }
    }
?>
```